# how to create a linked server to a SharePoint site in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I keep reading articles online that say this is possible but nothing that says how to do it. I have an SQL Server 2014 server and I want to create a linked server to a SharePoint site. I can go to Server Objects > Linked Server > New but then I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1.Open SQL Server Management Studio, enter the name of your local SQL Server, and then select Connect.

2.Expand Server Objects, right-click Linked Servers, and then select New Linked Server. To see Server Objects, connect to a local on-premises SQL Server. Then, Server Objects should be displayed.

3.In the Linked server text box, enter the full network name of the SQL Server you want to link to.

4.Under Server type, select SQL Server.

5.In the left pane, select Security. In this step, you map the local account you created to the remote server login.

6.Select Add, and enter the following:

a.Under Local Login, select the local account you created.

b.Check Impersonate if the local login also exists on the remote server.

c.Alternatively, if the local login will be mapped to a remote SQL Server login you, enter the Remote User name and Remote Password for the remote server login.

7.In the left pane, choose Server Options. Set the RPC and RPC Out parameters to True, and then select OK.

**Articles**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-create-a-linked-server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine

If you want to access SharePoint data from other application, I suggest you use SharePoint API(CSOM(C#), REST API or web service) to achieve it.

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint client library code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)

[Complete basic operations using SharePoint REST endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)

Comment: The steps you provided do not work for adding a SharePoint site as a linked server. And how can I use SharePoint client library code or REST in TSQL on the SQL server?